# Powershell Inkove-expression

Tags: powershell

Yesterday I read about the **`invoke-expression`**
from 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347550.aspx

```
invoke-expression -command "c:\batfile.bat"
```

It works very well, but how can I get the results and also , how to add `args` for ***.bat file***?

Answer (score 0):

Invoke-Expression is to Call up the EXpression,And '.Bat' is not an expression.

So if you want to call .Bat File Just`c:\batfile.bat` Could Do the trick.

Or if you want to explore on the invoke-expression Copy the commands in Batch file into a variable to see the code being executed.

There was similar instance where I had to do something similar,And I had used it as

```
$prog="cmd.exe"
$TARGETDIR = 'd:\temp'
$x='C:\Users\v-chetak\Desktop\1.bat'
$params=@("/C";"$x";" >d:\temp\result17.txt")
Start-Process -Verb runas $prog +$params
```

The  `$params` Will Hold all the arguments you want to pass.

Comment: How can I get the bat file logs and store them to a variable in powershell

Comment: >d:\temp\result17.txt This does it,In here the logs created by my 1.bat is pushed into >d:\temp\result17.txt file ,You Can tweak this the way you want

Comment: In my Code ,You can Change Start-Process -Verb runas $prog +$params to Start-Process $prog +$params  if you don't want to run Batch file in Admin mode